# Change DevExpress XAF form controls events

Tags: forms, devexpress, controls, xaf

I want to change my XAF form control's events.  I have tried some methods but they didn't work, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
            var input = document.getElementsByName("v4$MainLayoutEdit$xaf_l33$xaf_dviMiddleName_Edit");
            input.onclick = function () {
            alert('h fjkdsfjsd fsd kldfsjk fjdsk fjsdj');
            }
        };
</script>
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [ViewController](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/clsDevExpressExpressAppViewControllertopic) or a [WindowController](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/clsDevExpressExpressAppWindowControllertopic) to the web module of your XAF solution.

For some examples of similar issues, check out these issues and examples.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q309356
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q306205
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q325769

Here is a full-blown sample project:
*How to highlight the focused editor in DetailView*

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2106

As always with DevExpress controls, the best place to ask is the [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center).